# Determine which types require a length specification

Tags: sql-server, metadata, dynamic-sql

How do I determine whether a type requires length specification?
*Ideally, I'd like to know this by type. INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS mentioned by @ZoharPeled below lists the information by column, but it has only types that correspond with columns that already exist in the database, not every possible type.*

While generating dynamic SQL for which I do not know the data type or name until runtime, I need to create a table variable to store the `Inserted.X results`.

I recorded the data types from a query to `sys.columns`, however, I need also to specify the length of certain types. I can get that from `sys.columns.max_length`. However, some types such as *int* produce an error when length is specified (e.g. `DECLARE @n int(4)`), and I haven't been able to figure out how to tell how each must be declared.

In the SQL below, `name` and `md5` *must* have a length and `Id` must *not*:

```
DECLARE @_cnb TABLE (Id int, name nvarchar, md5 varbinary);
INSERT INTO dbo._users (name, md5)
OUTPUT Inserted.Id, Inserted.name, Inserted.md5 INTO @_cnb
VALUES (@a,@b) OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
-- Do stuff with contents of table variable
```

---

### How I am generating SQL:

I need to be able to support every major database, so each has a template for different actions. The in-progress MS SQL insert template is:

```
BEGIN
{0}
INSERT INTO {1} ({2})
OUTPUT {3} INTO @_cnb
VALUES ({4}) OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
{5}
END;
```

I then fill in each section. {1} is the `table.schema`, {3} is "Inserted.FOO, Inserted.BAR", etc.

Before adding joined table support, the previous template generated SQL like so:

```
INSERT INTO _users
    (first_name,last_name,site_id,site_id2,name)
VALUES (@a,@b,@c,@d,@e)
```

Now (sigh) it looks more like:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @_cnb TABLE (Id int,first_name nvarchar,last_name nvarchar,site_id int,site_id2 int);
INSERT INTO dbo._users (first_name,last_name,site_id,site_id2)
OUTPUT Inserted.Id, Inserted.first_name, Inserted.last_name, Inserted.site_id, Inserted.site_id2 INTO @_cnb
VALUES (@a,@b,@c,@d) OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
INSERT INTO dbo._user_access (user_id,access_id)
SELECT Id,@e FROM @_cnb;
-- others
INSERT INTO dbo._cars2 (user_id,name)
SELECT Id,@n FROM @_cnb;
END;
```

As for building `{0}`, `{1}`, etc. it's just a lot of manual string manipulation.

Comment: could you add some info on why you are generating dymamic sql,so that it can help understand more

Comment: There are not much of such types which require length - check whether it is one of those and use max_length to complete that dynamic sql. Also note numeric types with precision and scale.

Comment: You can use `INFROMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` instead, in that view, when there should be no content length the `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` column is null, and when it's max (like in varchar(max) or varbinary(max) it states `-1`.

Comment: @TheGameiswar: Added dynamic SQL generation details

Comment: @IvanStarostin: That's where I was headed: Storing whether a length specification is needed by type. I really want to avoid that because I'll need to add any new types as they are added to each DBMS, but it doesn't happen all that often.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: I *had* been avoiding `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` to allow for possible compatibility with MS SQL 2000, but that version is so primitive that I'll probably drop the idea. It already lacks support for `RETURNING...INTO`, a solution to which would be difficult.
`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` also occasionally has breaking changes and it doesn't tell me a size for e.g. `VARCHAR(MAX)` (I can't use `-1`), but I think I can work around that reliably.
Please post your message as an answer and I'll mark it as the solution unless someone figures out an even better one.

Comment: Oh, nice. While I don't have a schema using every data type, `-1` appears to show up *only* for `foo(max)` types.
`DATETIME_PRECISION` also looks valuable, but fortunately MSSQL's `DATETIME2` defaults to the highest precision, so I needn't specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` instead, in that view, when there should be no content length the `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` column is null, and when it's max (like in `varchar(max)` or `varbinary(max)` it states -1